# Access object in javascript onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, events, onclick

How can I access an object in a function that is called from the onclick event of a DOM element?

```
<script>
function myObj(){
    //...
}
myObj.prototype.doStep = function (num) {
    //...
}
var obj = new myObj();
function process_step(n) {
    //do something with the existing obj
    obj.doStep(n); //obj is undefined
}
$("body").append("<button onclick='process_step(1)'>Process Step 1</button>");
</script>
```

Comment: and what is `myObj` exactly? Where is the code-line that defines that object?

Comment: [works fine for me with a dummy `myObj`](http://jsfiddle.net/nnxm98or/)

Comment: Change `obj = new myObj();` to `var obj = new myObj();`. This might do the trick.

Comment: I have added myObj to the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<script>
  function myObj(){
    //...
  }
  myObj.prototype.doStep = function (num) {
    console.log(num);
  }
  var obj = new myObj();

  myObj.prototype.process_step = function(n) {
     this.doStep(n); //obj is undefined
  }

  obj.process_step(1);

    $("body").append("<button onclick='process_step(1)'>Process Step 1</button>");
    </script>
```

Comment: I don't think that's helping me get around the undefined obj in the process_step function. I need to do lots of other things with that obj.

Comment: If you are working with prototype, you need to do like that. Ok good lucky.

Comment: See it, maybe can help you http://javascriptissexy.com/oop-in-javascript-what-you-need-to-know   . There are some examples that how to do it